# Characterize semisimple rings of quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

**Problem**

Let $K$ be a field. Characterize all polynomials $f\in K[X]$ such that $R=K[X]/\langle f\rangle$ is a semisimple ring.

I know two equivalent definitions of semisimple modules but I am not so sure if they are useful for this exercise: a module is semisimple if it is a direct sum of simple submodules and, equivalently, if every submodule is a direct summand. I couldn't arrive to anything using these two definitions, maybe there is another property of semisimple rings or semisimple modules which could help with this problem, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A commutative ring is semisimple iff it is isomorphic to a finite direct product of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010844/commutative-ring-is-semisimple-iff-its-isomorphic-to-finite-direct-product-of-f).

Let $f$ be a polynomial in $K[x]$. Decompose $p$ into irreducible factors like $f=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ with $p_i$ irreducible and $e_i\ge 1$. Then, by CRT we get $K[x]/(f)\simeq k[x]/(p_1^{e_1})\times\cdots\times k[x]/(p_r^{e_r})$. If $e_i=1$ for all $i$, then $K[x]/(f)$ is isomorphic to a direct product of fields (since $K[x]/(p)$ is a field whenever $p$ is irreducible). If some $e_i>1$, then $k[x]/(p_i^{e_i})$ can't be contained in a (finite) direct product of fields (why?), and thus we can conclude:

> $K[x]/(f)$ is semisimple iff $f$ is a product of mutually distinct irreducible factors.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this a month later but I came to this problem again and rereading your solution I've realized I don't get why $k[x]/({p_i}^{e_i})$ can't be contained in a finite direct product of fields (for $e_i>1$). Could you help me with that?

Comment: @user156441 Because it has non-zero nilpotents and a direct product of fields don't.

Comment: Got it, thanks!