# Do we have "basic building block" in ring theory, analogous to group

Tags: ring-theory

As far as I know, classification of simple groups is very important in group theory, since these are the "basic building blocks". So do we have similar things in ring theory, at least for commutative ring? Also do we have "similar" short exact sequence in ring theory?

Thank you!

Comment: This classification is only for finite groups; there is a similar classification of finite-dimensional simple Lie groups, of course. But there is no hope classifying all simple groups.

Comment: As for the commutative rings: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010844/commutative-ring-is-semisimple-iff-its-isomorphic-to-a-finite-direct-product-of?rq=1